# Is it correct to say "He went across the street" in this situation?

Tags: phrase-usage

[image]

We often use "**go across**" without an intersection involved.

Can we say "**Tom went across street A**"?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you could say “Tom crossed the street” or “Tom crossed (A) street.”

Crossing the street simply means to walk from one side to the other. You can cross the street at an intersection, or not at an  intersection. It is physically possible to cross the street anywhere, but there may be some places where it is not legal.

Comment: Went across is OK too.

Answer (score 0):

It does seem odd not to mention the crossroads.

> [Walking along B Street,] Tom passed the intersection with A Street.
>
> Tom walked over the crossroads at A Street.

Comment: The drawing looks like an intersection and the person walking looks like they are in the middle of the street.